# JSF2.0 Primefaces automatically redirects instead of forwarding

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to create a website using PrimeFaces and NetBeans,
I'm using the DefaultMenuItem class to dynamically create the menu but when I use either setUrl or setOutcome the site redirects instead of forwarding.
Here's a piece of my code

```
DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem(obEvet.getcEvent());
item.setUrl(obEveto.getcName());
System.out.println("MenuView:" + obEvet.getcName() + "  " + obEvet.getcModule() + "  " + obEvet.getcEvent());
item.setAjax(false);
firstSubmenu.addElement(item);
```

The menu is configured in two parts, the first one loads the companies, the second one loads the available modules depending on what company I selected.
Please note that this problem only happens when I click any of the elements of the second list.

Comment: what is the System.out result?

Comment: @ÖmerFarukKurt "Information:   MenuView:/cat/ope/CtEng/index.xhtml  CATALOGS  Eng
Information:   MenuView:/cat/ope/CtCar/index.xhtml  CATALOGS  Eng2"

and so on.